# slattach speed error (17.10)

Tags: serial-port

I am playing around with serial port networking and I can't get slattach to change the speed of my serial port from the default/last set.
The speed change works with putty but not with slattach.

```
sudo slattach -s 28800 /dev/ttyUSB0 
slattach: tty_open: cannot set 28800 bps!
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2880bps is not a valid speed on most serial chips.

Common speeds are 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600 and 115200bps. I would suggest using the highest speed at which you get a stable connection. Typically 115.2kbps is fine over short cables. If you want longer cables, you should investigate RS-485, which can pull high speeds over long distances by using differential signalling.

Comment: ah, now it works. I thought that my adapter had more speeds.